# How to divide script for each individual component

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my index.html file I want global styles and scripts on each html page so i want it to be at one place and other scripts which are related to each individual page e.g dashboard html have its own scripts so I want to add dashboard scripts to be in its html:

[image]

I am creating my Application and I have downloaded the Template for it based on HTML, CSS, JS AND JQUERY now I am converting it in to angular components for this I am having issues in loading Javascript files.

I have loaded my common scripts in Index.html which is shared in my all the components.

Now I want to load my scripts which are not shared. This means each component have its own scripts, and I don't want to load those scripts in index.html file because of performance issues.

I have seen some answers related to this that we have to make scripts tag in the component for solving this problem. 
Is there any other approach?

Comment: Please provide some code. From you question it doesn't even look Angular related. Angular JS questions should have the `angularjs` tag instead of `angular`.

Comment: it is related to angular . let me post some SS

Comment: What is "my common scripts"? What is "all my components"? Sounds like you are looking for lazy loading. Please try some Google search.

Comment: common scripts are those scripts which is shared in my other components.. those scripts i loaded in Index.html header.

Comment: some scripts are not common and are used in individual component. so i can not load those scripts in html of individual component because there is no head on it . how can  i load those ?

Comment: Please add some code. What are "some scripts"? In Angular you build the application and the build step takes care of the "scripts".

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i have added the image kindly check it